# How can I correctly implement this simple query using the "query methods" of Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am absolutly new in **Spring Data JPA** project and I have the following problem.

I have these 2 classes that map 2 tables and the related relationship that connect between them.

1) **Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo** that map the **TGU1002_ANAGRAFEPROFILO** table on my DB:

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the TGU1002_ANAGRAFEPROFILO database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="profdb.TGU1002_ANAGRAFEPROFILO")
@NamedQuery(name="Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo t")
public class Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COD_PRF")
    private String codPrf;

    @Column(name="COD_PGM_ULT_MOV")
    private String codPgmUltMov;

    @Column(name="COD_UTE_ULT_MOV")
    private String codUteUltMov;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="DAT_ORA_ULT_MOV")
    private Date datOraUltMov;

    @Column(name="DES_PRF")
    private String desPrf;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="COD_APP")
    private Tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo")
    private List<Tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto> tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
      @JoinTable(name="profdb.TGU1008_PROFILOFUNZIONE",
         joinColumns=
             @JoinColumn(name="COD_PRF", referencedColumnName="COD_PRF"),
         inverseJoinColumns=
             @JoinColumn(name="COD_FNZ", referencedColumnName="COD_FNZ")
         )
    //@JoinColumn(name="COD_PRF")
    private List<Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione> tgu1003Anagrafefunziones;

    public Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo() {
    }

    public String getCodPrf() {
        return this.codPrf;
    }

    public void setCodPrf(String codPrf) {
        this.codPrf = codPrf;
    }

    public String getCodPgmUltMov() {
        return this.codPgmUltMov;
    }

    public void setCodPgmUltMov(String codPgmUltMov) {
        this.codPgmUltMov = codPgmUltMov;
    }

    public String getCodUteUltMov() {
        return this.codUteUltMov;
    }

    public void setCodUteUltMov(String codUteUltMov) {
        this.codUteUltMov = codUteUltMov;
    }

    public Date getDatOraUltMov() {
        return this.datOraUltMov;
    }

    public void setDatOraUltMov(Date datOraUltMov) {
        this.datOraUltMov = datOraUltMov;
    }

    public String getDesPrf() {
        return this.desPrf;
    }

    public void setDesPrf(String desPrf) {
        this.desPrf = desPrf;
    }

    public Tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione getTgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione() {
        return this.tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione;
    }

    public void setTgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione(Tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione) {
        this.tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione = tgu1001Anagrafeapplicazione;
    }

    public List<Tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto> getTgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos() {
        return this.tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos;
    }

    public void setTgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos(List<Tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto> tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos) {
        this.tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos = tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos;
    }

    public Tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto addTgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto(Tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto) {
        getTgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos().add(tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto);
        tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto.setTgu1002Anagrafeprofilo(this);

        return tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto;
    }

    public Tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto removeTgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto(Tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto) {
        getTgu1007Gesutenteprfcontestos().remove(tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto);
        tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto.setTgu1002Anagrafeprofilo(null);

        return tgu1007Gesutenteprfcontesto;
    }

    public List<Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione> getTgu1003Anagrafefunziones() {
        return this.tgu1003Anagrafefunziones;
    }

    public void setTgu1003Anagrafefunziones(List<Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione> tgu1003Anagrafefunziones) {
        this.tgu1003Anagrafefunziones = tgu1003Anagrafefunziones;
    }

}
```

2) **Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione** class that map the **TGU1003_ANAGRAFEFUNZIONE** table on the database:

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the TGU1003_ANAGRAFEFUNZIONE database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="profdb.TGU1003_ANAGRAFEFUNZIONE")
@NamedQuery(name="Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione t")
public class Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COD_FNZ")
    private String codFnz;

    @Column(name="COD_PGM_ULT_MOV")
    private String codPgmUltMov;

    @Column(name="COD_UTE_ULT_MOV")
    private String codUteUltMov;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="DAT_ORA_ULT_MOV")
    private Date datOraUltMov;

    @Column(name="DES_FNZ")
    private String desFnz;

    @Column(name="DES_URL_FNZ")
    private String desUrlFnz;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Tgu1004Tipofunzione
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="COD_TIP_FNZ")
    private Tgu1004Tipofunzione tgu1004Tipofunzione;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tgu1003Anagrafefunziones")
    private List<Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo> tgu1002Anagrafeprofilos;

    public Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione() {
    }

    public String getCodFnz() {
        return this.codFnz;
    }

    public void setCodFnz(String codFnz) {
        this.codFnz = codFnz;
    }

    public String getCodPgmUltMov() {
        return this.codPgmUltMov;
    }

    public void setCodPgmUltMov(String codPgmUltMov) {
        this.codPgmUltMov = codPgmUltMov;
    }

    public String getCodUteUltMov() {
        return this.codUteUltMov;
    }

    public void setCodUteUltMov(String codUteUltMov) {
        this.codUteUltMov = codUteUltMov;
    }

    public Date getDatOraUltMov() {
        return this.datOraUltMov;
    }

    public void setDatOraUltMov(Date datOraUltMov) {
        this.datOraUltMov = datOraUltMov;
    }

    public String getDesFnz() {
        return this.desFnz;
    }

    public void setDesFnz(String desFnz) {
        this.desFnz = desFnz;
    }

    public String getDesUrlFnz() {
        return this.desUrlFnz;
    }

    public void setDesUrlFnz(String desUrlFnz) {
        this.desUrlFnz = desUrlFnz;
    }

    public Tgu1004Tipofunzione getTgu1004Tipofunzione() {
        return this.tgu1004Tipofunzione;
    }

    public void setTgu1004Tipofunzione(Tgu1004Tipofunzione tgu1004Tipofunzione) {
        this.tgu1004Tipofunzione = tgu1004Tipofunzione;
    }

    public List<Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo> getTgu1002Anagrafeprofilos() {
        return this.tgu1002Anagrafeprofilos;
    }

    public void setTgu1002Anagrafeprofilos(List<Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo> tgu1002Anagrafeprofilos) {
        this.tgu1002Anagrafeprofilos = tgu1002Anagrafeprofilos;
    }

}
```

As you can see in the **Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo** class there is definied a **biderectional many-to-many association to Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione** class (in the relatiolan model on the DB it is passing to another association table), this one:

```
//bi-directional many-to-many association to Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name="profdb.TGU1008_PROFILOFUNZIONE",
     joinColumns=
         @JoinColumn(name="COD_PRF", referencedColumnName="COD_PRF"),
     inverseJoinColumns=
         @JoinColumn(name="COD_FNZ", referencedColumnName="COD_FNZ")
     )
//@JoinColumn(name="COD_PRF")
private List<Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione> tgu1003Anagrafefunziones;
```

So in this project to perform query it is used the so called **Query creation from method names**, here a reference:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods

So, I will have a repository interface that contain something like this to perform the query (this is another repository class found in this project, only to show how it is done):

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass=Tid022Anagraficarup.class, idClass=Integer.class)
public interface Tid022AnagraficarupRepository extends JpaRepository<Tid022Anagraficarup, Integer> { 

    public Tid022Anagraficarup findByCodFisRup(@Param("codFisRup") String codFisRup);
}
```

So I think that this repository is based to a class named **Tid022Anagraficarup** and perform aqyery on this table using the value of the **codFisRup** paramter defined in this class\table.

So coming back to the problem related to the my previous entity mapped class I have to implement a simply query (using a method as in the other repository) that do the following thing:

Retrieve the list of all **Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione** objcts, this one:

```
private List<Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione> tgu1003Anagrafefunziones;
```

of an **Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo** haiving a specific value of the **codPrf** field.

So I have implement the repository interface based on the **Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo** class, something like this:

```
@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass=Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo.class, idClass=String.class)
public interface Tgu1002AnagrafeprofiloRepository extends JpaRepository<Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo, String> { 
    ........................................................
    ........................................................
    HERE THE QUERY METHOD DEFINITION
    ........................................................
    ........................................................

}
```

And now I think that I have "only" to define the query method using the same system of the prvious repository class but I have not many ideas about how do it.

I am thinking that maybe I can only find by the **codPrf** value of the **Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo** passing it as parameter because the list of **Tgu1003Anagrafefunzione** related object that I want to retrieve seems be eagerly loaded, so maybe it is automatically retrieved when I retrive the **Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo** object.

Can you give me some suggestion about how implement this query using Spring Data JPA?

Answer (score 0):

To create a finder that returns all `Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo` entities with a given `codPrf`, all you need to do is to declare an interface as:

```
public interface Tgu1002AnagrafeprofiloRepository extends JpaRepository<Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo, String> {
          List<Tgu1002Anagrafeprofilo> findByCodPrf(String codPrf);
}
```

Once that is done, check your Spring configuration. If Data JPA is used already, the configuration shall contain an annotation that wakes up the framework: `@EnableJpaRepositories`. The annotation might also list package(s) where the framework looks for your DAOs, so make sure the correct ones are listed.

That's basically it. Once both the interface and the annotation are in place, just have an instance of the DAO `@Inject`ed where needed.

EDIT: If the relations of your entities are setup correctly, you indeed can get then from the entities obtained from the finder.